# Generar una matriz a partir de una lista

Tags: python, array, lista

Tengo un archivo con 5 variables (tipo lista, donde cada una tiene un montón de datos) y necesito generar una matriz en donde cada columna tenga los datos de cada variable.

El código es:

```
data = load('87576_wrf.npz')
lst = data.files
print(lst)
['max48', 'fecha', 'min24', 'max24', 'min48']
```

Y si veo los datos adentro de la lista (no se a que variable corresponden):

```
for item in lst:
print(data[item])

1.70873125e+01  1.19996250e+01  1.90101250e+01  2.13876250e+01
1.76940625e+01  1.88091875e+01  1.83152500e+01  2.24105000e+01
1.81945000e+01  2.07007500e+01  1.80163125e+01  1.99025000e+01....
```

Como hago para generar una matriz en donde cada columna sea una variable:

```
vector=np.array(lst)
['max48' 'fecha' 'min24' 'max24' 'min48']
```

y abajo de cada variable estén sus respectivos datos.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, en `data.files` tienes una lista de nombres, y en `data["item"]` tienes los datos correspondientes a cada uno de los nombres "item".

Esto sugiere que `data` presenta una interfaz como la de un diccionario python, al permitir acceder a las listas de datos a través de la clave "item".

Quieres convertir todo ello a un array (asumo que todas las listas `data["item"]` tienen la misma longitud). El problema es que un array numpy no tiene estructura de diccionario. Si bien podrías construir un array como el que buscas así:

```
array = np.array([ column for column in data.values() ]).T
```

en realidad no sabrías a qué "item" corresponde cada columna, pues el array almacenará sólo los números en sí, y no las claves. Lo que es peor, el orden de un diccionario no es predecible (al menos no antes de python 3.7), por lo que la línea anterior puede darte un resultado diferente cada vez (es decir, con las columnas ordenadas de diferente forma).

Se me ocurren tres soluciones:

1. Forzar a recorrer las columnas en un orden prefijado, para que el resultado sea predecible. Por ejemplo por el orden en que te son retornados en `data.files`:

   ```
   array = np.array([ data[item] for item in data.files ]).T
   ```

   o por orden alfabético:

   ```
   array = np.array([ data[item] for item in sorted(data.files) ]).T
   ```

   En ambos casos la `.T` final es para obtener la matriz "transpuesta", es decir, cambiar filas por columnas
2. Usar pandas, que está específicamente diseñado para datos tabulares con diferentes nombres de columna. En este caso, si realmente `data` implementa el protocolo de diccionario, debería bastar con lo siguiente:

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   ```

   o bien `df = pd.DataFrame(data.items())`
3. Usar arrays estructurados de Numpy. Son una característica que he visto muy pocas veces, pero que podría servir para este caso. En este tipo de arrays cada fila se considera un "registro" en la que cada elemento tiene su nombre. Así, en tu caso, los nombres de los elementos de cada fila serían las cadenas en `data.files`.

   El problema de esta solución es que es muy engorrosa de construir (pues tienes que pasarle los datos por filas en vez de por columnas, y cada fila ha de ser una tupla):

   ```
   array = np.array([data[item] for item in data.files ]).T
   estructurado = np.array([tuple(row) for row in array],
                           dtype=[(item, "float") for item in data.files])
   ```

   Ahora puedes acceder por su nombre a los datos de una columna, por ejemplo `estructurado["min24"]`. Si en cambio pones algo como `estructurado[2]` estarás accediendo por fila.

**Nota** Ya que no tengo tu fichero, ni detalles sobre el tipo que retorna `load()`, no he podido probar ninguna de las soluciones anteriores.